# ElasticSearch - 2nd Level nested aggregation incorrect doc_count

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregation

ElasticSearch 7.10.1 nested aggregations.

Can anyone point me to why the doc_count on my 2nd nested aggregation is not correct?
The count on the first aggregation is accurate but the 2nd isnt (both are keyword fields).

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "products": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "productsImpacted"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "field1": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "productsImpacted.product.keyword",
            "size": 1000
          },
            "aggs": {
              "resellers": {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "requestType"
                },
                "aggs": {
                  "field2": {
                    "terms": {
                      "field": "requestType.type.keyword",
                      "size": 1000
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

ES’agg is inaccurate.
you cna use `size` and `shard_size` to improve accuracy means a decline in performance，You can refer to the official documents：
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-shard-size

Comment: Thanks for the info, i aready enabled show_term_doc_count_error  and upped the shardsize option to the max but its still not correct (show_term_doc_count_error shows no error count). There are only a couple of hundred docs in the index as well so i cant see how it would be inacurate with such a low record count.  The first aggregate is also acurate.